# PHP: Unable to extract ID from dynamically created URL

Tags: php, url, dynamic

A landing page on my website displays all the links relating to that section (recipes), using a for loop. This works fine. But I then need to extract the id generated in that for loop, to populate the page being generated.

I can't figure how to extract that id value (neither `$_REQUEST['id']` nor `$_REQUEST['id=?']`; i suspect both are definitely wrong). Is it through manipulating the URL string or is there another way? Following is the related code:

```
<?php 
                $id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

                if ($id) {// user gets here by clicking on link with id
                $query  = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE uniqno = $id";
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $data = $row // fetch data from database

                ?>
                <p><?php echo $data['ingredcontent']; ?></p>

                <?php }
                else {
                foreach ($reciperow as $recipe) { ?>

                <a href="?id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>"><h2><?php echo $recipe['rectitle'];?></h2></a>

                <p class="subhead"><?php echo $recipe['recsummary']; ?></p>

<?php }} ?>
```

Would appreciate if anyone could advise what I should pass to $_REQUEST to ensure it pulls out the 'id' defined in the foreach loop. (**note**: I'm intentionally staying away from PHP routing since this is a very basic project).

Comment: where does $reciperow come from? is it empty ? $_GET['id'] should be fine if you can see the id in the uri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code as below, please check if this is what you want

```html
<?php 
$conn=new mysqli($hostname, $dbuser, $dbpassword, $dbname);//i assume you have this somewhere

                if (isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {// user gets here by clicking on link with id
                $query  = "SELECT * FROM recipes WHERE uniqno = ".$_REQUEST['id']; //not necessary to convert $_REQUEST to integer
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $data = $row // fetch data from database

                ?>
                <p><?php echo $data[0]['ingredcontent']; //you fetch all... need to set index(row) ?></p>

                <?php }
                else {
    //so i assume your $reciperow is fetching all data:
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM recipes"; //not necessary to convert $_REQUEST to integer
                $result = $conn->query($query);
                $reciperow= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    
                foreach ($reciperow as $recipe) { ?>

                <a href="?id=<?php echo $recipe['uniqno'];?>"><h2><?php echo $recipe['rectitle'];?></h2></a>

                <p class="subhead"><?php echo $recipe['recsummary']; ?></p>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: See Youuu, yes this works - would also be nice to know why `$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);

                if ($id)` doesn't work?

Comment: before you use intval, you need to make sure the $_REQUEST is exist first. so i use isset() function instead. Also, that's not necessary to convert into integer since your purpose is to use the id as a 'string' inside your sql query

Comment: thanks - one more question: why the dot before $?   ie.uniqno = ".$_REQUEST['id']   not   uniqno = "$_REQUEST['id']

Comment: the dot(.) in PHP is a string connector. you need to use dot(.) to join string and a variable.

Comment: but in this case what is the dot (.) connecting to? since that is the only term in the ""?

Comment: It's connecting directly to $_REQUEST[“id”]

Comment: got it - sorry about that - i must be blind.